# How to put HTTP Basic Auth as Part of Sonatype Nexus URL for artifact Download?

Tags: nexus, basic-authentication

I am able to download the file from Sonatype Nexus using HTTP Basic Authentication Credentials in the HTTP Header.

But I am not able to achieve this by putting in the credentials as part of the url - something like this:

```
http://admin:admin123@nexus.example.com/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.test&a=project&v=1.0&r=test_repo_1_release
```

Does anyone know why or how I can achieve the same thing without using auth in headers?

PS: this is a test environment - hence no SSL.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the authorization header, so you need to use a client that can set the authorizaiton http header. If you have curl or wget available you can do this as:

curl -u admin:admin123 http://nexus.example.com/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.test&a=project&v=1.0&r=test_repo_1_release

wget --user=admin --password=admin123 http://nexus.example.com/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.test&a=project&v=1.0&r=test_repo_1_release

Comment: Well knew that already and was able to do that.. The question was if it is possible to do it using the URL only...

Comment: But what about a simple desktop browser? How to make Nexus prompt for username and password (Basic Auth) instead of redirecting to the Nexus UI?

Comment: Up-voted "what's about simple desktop browser" or actually tools like "jenkins" that allow to install a binary from repository with only option to provide URL (Global Tool Configuration) with no extra choice to provide authentication.

Comment: Seconded @IliaShakitko - I'm trying to get an artifact from a Bamboo pipeline - the answer given completely misses the point.

Comment: URL authentication is not secure... but it does work with Nexus.  For instance: curl "http://admin:admin123@localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/ant/ant/1.5.4/ant-1.5.4.pom" will work.   What error are you receiving?

Comment: without using curl or wget , is it possible to authenticate the repository directly via HTTP header

Comment: I don't care about security right now, I need to test that it is working...